# Android: делание невидимым View в LinearLayout

Tags: android, java

Всем привет! Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой.

Пользователь может создавать (добавлять в активность) новые элементы (layout'ы):

```
    layout_container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_items);
View view_item = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.shop_item,layout_container,false);
            layout_container.addView(view_item);
            buy_name[field_count] = (EditText) view_item.findViewById(R.id.editText_text);
```

А также пользователь может удалять их (делать невидимыми **setVisibility(View.GONE)**)

```
                buy_name[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Проблема в том, что виджеты действительно становятся невидимыми, но всё равно остаётся пустое место, которые как-будто не заполнили. Пробовал делать сам layout, внутри котого виджеты, невидимым - не помогло.

Вопрос - можно ли как-то добавленный в **linear_container** view сделать невидимым полностью, чтобы не было пустого места?

Простите, если вопрос поставлен некорректно.

Спасибо!

Comment: А почему не используете ListView?

Comment: Не подходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для таких целей принято использовать [ViewStub](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html)